# PHP is not showing up my error message when can't connect to database

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

I try to create my own echo message when someone can't connect to database. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

if(!$conn){
    echo "Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
echo "test";
?>
```

It looks like PHP is terminating my whole code when it is encountering an error (for example typo in user name) while connecting to db. I'm getting and fatal error generated by PHP interpreter instead of "Connection failed" written by me. It's not even showing up my test echo;

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'roo'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php(3): mysqli_connect('localhost', 'roo', '', 'test') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 3
```

I already tried:

- adding error_reporting(0) at first possible code line (it's not working at all),
- adding `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` (also not working at all)

Comment: you can add a try to add a `try` block

Comment: The code does not match the error message. One says user `root` the other `roo`.

Comment: thats typo i used to check is my code working

Comment: @MarkusZeller question says "for example typo's in the username" - the question is about how to catch errors/ handle errors properly in PHP rather than the error seen there.

Comment: Also note that this is what PHP is _supposed_ to do. When you request a PHP route, the server starts up php, asks it to do its job, and then php terminates again when it's done generating the output data. It's not supposed to keep going when an error occurs, it's supposed to die with an error message, and then it's your server's responsibility to somehow gracefully handle that (i.e. PHP crashing should not take down the server itself =)

Comment: Add to start of script to display all errors. ini_set('display_errors', 1);ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @FilipPieprzyk don't show errors for different code from what's in your post: rerun it with the real values, and make sure to show _that_ error (and just to cover your bases, actually rereun it, don't just edit the post without that). Having said that: if PHP can't connect then you almost certainly can't connect either: fire up a terminal, make sure you're _not_ root, and try to connect to mysql with the root username and without a password. Good bet the mysql CLI goes "nope, won't let you do that". (which is why you should always make a real mysql user with dbtable access granted as needed)

Comment: Never use `error_reporting(0)`. This turns off all error reporting

Comment: "when someone can't connect to database" That shouldn't be the case. You should have only one user signing in to the database and that user should be secret to your site's users. That means you don't need to check whether they can connect or not

Comment: @Dharman at least is there a way to chagne the format of fatal errors?

Comment: What do you mean format of fatal errors? The fatal error should stop your application, respond to the browser with status 500 and log the error message in a file on the server. How you present page 500 is up to your project

Comment: By format I mean the message it outputs. For example I would like to get something like "Something broke!" instead of getting a db host, user, password and dbname

Comment: Temporary I disabled display_errors in php.ini. I just want to know is there a way to change the message it outputs e.g. when I commit a typo in php code or where my mysql server is dead for some reason. Everyone can say sensetive data like passwords when it happens

Comment: The error itself is as dangerous as the password. You **should never do** anything like  `echo "Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error();` or  `echo 'My error:'. $e->getMessage();`.

Comment: What is most important, your fixation on the connection error just makes no sense. The error could be anywhere. You should have a code that handles any error, not just a database connection error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to enable errors:

```php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Enter code with try catch, like this:

```php
<?php

try{
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

    if(!$conn){
        echo "Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
   echo 'My error:'. $e->getMessage();
}
```

If it will null result you also can try **register_shutdown_function**

```php
function shutdown() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($error['type'] === E_ERROR) {
        // there are errors
    }
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

myNotExistsFunction();
// Will give error
```

Comment: It works exactly as I wanted to. Thank you!

Comment: Here you are. )

Comment: @FilipPieprzyk this code doesn't do what you want. It doesn't hide errors from the user. This try catch block is one of the most useless codes in the world

Comment: @TuralRzaxanov you seems to misunderstood the question. It is not how to show the error message but how to **hide** it. On a live site one should never display any single PHP error message to the user. Therefore, 'display_errors' must be turned **OFF**

Comment: I right understood. He can hide error inside catch block. I wrote it like that to explain, php errors need to catch with try-catch syntax . He tried to catch or show with if block. With try-catch syntax, he will can hided errors if don't read echo function.